# Display time in Xcode breakpoint

Tags: xcode, swift, debugging, xcode6, breakpoints

In Xcode 6 I have created a breakpoint that do not interrupt the program execution to display informations.

[image]

Here is the result between results of `NSLog` calls:

[image]

I now want to add a time information to this message as done by `NSLog` does. How can I achieve this?

### Similar behavior

I know how to obtain such a result using `Debugger Command` but I want to know how to achieve it using `Log Message`:

[image]

Comment: I suppose you could use something like `@[NSDate date]@ - Hello!` but be aware that this will be printed in UTC and printing a local-timezone formatted date will be not a pretty one-liner... (unless you're willing to make a class extension on `NSDate` and write a method for it - didn't try it but could work)

Comment: The answer you gave me is for Objective-C but the project is in Swift. That's why I wonder if there is some way to add time in breakpoint with no use of expression in order to be language independent. It could be `%T` for example.

Answer (score 6):

As you can see in the hints: @exp@

so you can write this:

@[NSDate date]@ - some additional message

Output will be:

2018-06-28 14:06:45 UTC - some additional message

(works only for the 'Log Message' type)

Answer (score 4):

**Xcode log time**

Using Swift you are able to use `@Date().debugDescription@ my message` (UTC time)

[image]
[image]